# runtime error executing macro in excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am receiving:

> Run-time error '1004': Cannot run macro Makros.xlm!MakroIni. The
>   macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be
>   disabled.

...when running a Macro in certain instances of Excel 2010. In some Excel 2010 installations and Excel 2003 it works fine.

There are 2 Workbooks involved: Macro.xlm and Username.xls. Both files are stored on a remote server.

The Macro crashes when executing:

```
Workbooks.Open Makro_Path & Makro_Nam, ReadOnly:=True
Application.Run Makro_Nam & "!MakroIni", WbTyp
```

The first line is proper executed and all macros are visible. 
Makro_Nam is defined as:

```
Public Const Makro_Nam As String = "Makros.xlm"
```

What can i do?

Comment: Stupid guess but: are macros enabled in that instance of excel?

Comment: Yes macros are enabled in all instances. The macro actually runs to that certain point.

Comment: Have you tried using the full name (something like `Application.Run "'" & Makro_Path & Makro_Nam & "'!MakroIni"`)?

Comment: I tried it, but still no difference.

Comment: I just noticed the instances where this problem occur are 64 bit installations. When running other macros from the old workbook i get an error that i should run them ptr safe.

Comment: Can you show the complete code on how are you declaring the variables and finally running the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the cause was Excel 64 bit.

The Makro.xlm worksheet contained this function definitions:

```
Private Declare  Function FindFirstFile Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "FindFirstFileA" ( _
ByVal lpFileName As String, _
ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long
Private Declare  Function FindNextFile Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "FindNextFileA" ( _
ByVal hFindFile As Long, _
ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long
Private Declare  Function FindClose Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
ByVal hFindFile As Long) As Long
Private Declare  Function FileTimeToLocalFileTime Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
ByRef lpFileTime As FILETIME, _
ByRef lpLocalFileTime As FILETIME) As Long
Private Declare  Function FileTimeToSystemTime Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
ByRef lpFileTime As FILETIME, _
ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME) As Long
```

I changed them to ptrsafe:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindFirstFile Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "FindFirstFileA" ( _
ByVal lpFileName As String, _
ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindNextFile Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "FindNextFileA" ( _
ByVal hFindFile As Long, _
ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindClose Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
ByVal hFindFile As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FileTimeToLocalFileTime Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
ByRef lpFileTime As FILETIME, _
ByRef lpLocalFileTime As FILETIME) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FileTimeToSystemTime Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
ByRef lpFileTime As FILETIME, _
ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME) As Long
```

Now it seems to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what might have changed over the years, but in making a similar update I found I also needed to change the Long types to LongPtr for 64 bit compatibility.  Discussion here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your macro does, the obvious answer seems to be that you need to set

```
ReadOnly:=True
```

to be

```
ReadOnly:=False
```

So that your macro can make changes to the data.

Comment: Yeah seems kinda obvious, but isn't the cause for the problem. The Macro.xlm worksheet contains no Data. It only contains code that is used in all User worksheets.